# How can I use struct in Core Data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm trying to save `taskList` into Core Data using array called "taskArr" and I cant figure it out how to implement it. I've tried several things and nothing seems to work?

**Main VC:**

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

struct taskList{
     var name: String!
     var dateCreated: Date!
     var dueDate:Date!
}

private let listIdentifier = "listIdentifier"


var taskArr: [taskList] = []
```

**Save:**

```
   // Save Button
    @IBAction func doneButton_Tapped(_ sender: Any) {

        var newTask = taskList()
        newTask.name = taskNameField.text
        newTask.dueDate = dueDatePicker.date
        newTask.dateCreated = Date()

        taskArr.append(newTask)

        didCreateTask = true

        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: If you use Core Data anyway create a new entity and map the struct to that entity or even drop the struct.

Comment: I don't see anything related to Core Data in your code?

Comment: there is no code because iv deleted it, im asking how can i save to core data

Comment: You create a core data model, then add an entity to the model and write the appropriate code. Sounds that you first need to read an article or take a tutorial on Core Data before getting started.

Comment: the code below is before i deleted